# What is the time (and the evolution) for the experienced users to get an answer to their questions?

Tags: discussion, answers, users, statistics, data-explorer

#### Context

I am not asking a lot of questions on Stack Overflow, but for about 2-3 years I feel that I need to wait for more (and more frequently place a bounty) to get an answer.

This made me think if it is me or this issue of mine is more general. So, I tried to understand if the time required for fairly experienced users (I picked 1000 reputation as a minimum to reduce the record count considered in the heavy queries).

#### What I have tried

As suggested by Laurel is to compute the ratio between all questions asked by "experienced" users that received an answer in less than 7 days and all the questions asked by the experienced users.

Something like [this](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/1404738/percentage-of-experienced-users-questions-that-received-answer-in-less-than-a-wee).

Exported and made a very simple graph in Excel:

[image: How much of experienced users]

It seems that more and more experienced users got their question answered in 7 days at most. It would be interesting to know if they needed bounties for that or not.

I am interested in feedback about the assessment of how are things evolving for fairly experienced users (including the correctness of my queries).

Comment: considering the avg "inexperienced" user is a one question account that'll never ask another question, it's not unreasonable to expect time to answer to on avg be longer for such users... they don't have time to learn/improve with just one question.

Comment: i would expect it to be more of a bell curve when looked at the entire lifetime of the avg user who returns and becomes an engaged user. first few questions don't quite fit the network, then you get better at asking, and by being better at asking you also become better at solving... thus reducing the number of questions asked and increasing the... "difficulty" of the questions asked, thus moving back in the direction of longer wait times.

Comment: I have absolutely no clue what those graphs represent... It could at very least use a legend explaining what the axes are...

Comment: A quick and dirty way to make these data points more readable -- especially in the first graph -- is to multiply the `MONTH` by 8, which means that your data from (say) 2015 will range from 201512 to 201596 instead of 201501 to 201512. There's still a larger gap between December-January than between any other two months but it is not nearly as confusing to look at. (Of course it would be better still to plot these against a true date axis but you might have to resort to gnuplot/Excel for that)

Comment: If you are looking for feedback then please explain better what the topic is. Are you saying it's a problem that questions get answered less? This is pretty obvious. The more answers we have the less there is need to add more.

Comment: @Dharman The initial assumption is that it is harder to get your question answered if you are an experienced member (with another assumption that this implies higher quality / more complex / more relevant questions). I will need to change the queries and use Excel to be meaningful before anything else.

Comment: I have rebuilt the query and provided a decent graph. Now a trend can be identified, but I am not sure if the query correctly reflects what I need (a review of it is needed).

Comment: I would not be surprised if it is also specific to tag.

Comment: My first instinct is that "experienced" users are more likely to find existing content to answer their questions before asking. When they actually post a question, it's because it's a harder question than what you get from a new user that doesn't even bother to search before asking. Harder to answer means it takes longer to get any good responses. I'm not sure you can see any of that from just the average time to first answer, though. Number of views before first answer is likely also relevant, as is how long the Q was on that tag's "new questions" page.

Comment: Maybe use median instead of average.

Comment: If the quey is supposed to show the relation between rep and speed of answer, than why does it have dates? Axes should be rep vs. average time an answer received. I don't really understand what the graph is supposed to represent.

Comment: @Devolus The reputation is only used as a threshold (minimum value to consider a user "experienced" enough for their questions to be considered). I am interested in how the meantime to get an answer has evolved over time, not based on the reputation.

Comment: @TylerH Not sure if I can do that (I could barely run the query and not hit the timeout threshold). AVG (and probably other aggregation functions) are not supported, that's why I had to compute the sum and the count to get the average.

Answer (score 17):

I never used a bounty on my questions. On many questions I didn't receive an answer either, and a lot of them I answered myself after finding out the solution.

A bounty doesn't guarantee that you get an answer.

I think a more experienced user tends to ask questions which are harder to solve and thus the audience that can write an answer is smaller, which in turn means that there will be either no answers, or it takes longer to get one if at all.

Of course, even experienced users may have questions at topics where they are not good at, and those might attract more/faster answers.

Comment: I think the last point is probably more a big factor.  People with a high rep may be *experts* in one field but also wander over to other less familiar areas.

Comment: Would it make sense to somehow highlight questions from more experienced users (say 1000 rep and up).  Every now and then I read a really good question and realize it's from someone with 7.5k or something (unfortunately, it's rare that I can answer them).  But, I'd probably read those questions first.  Right now, if I look at the "front page" for C#, there are 15 questions.  Only 4 posters have more than one digit rep (from 27 to 302)

Comment: @Flydog57 You should make that a separate question/feature-request here on SE.I like that suggestion.

Comment: @Flydog57, That number is not surprising. When I look at `c/c++` it's pretty similar. I would say that 90% of the questions asked are basically the same. Sometimes I have the feeling that you can recognize from the questions, when some prof gave some homework, because there is a tendency that similar problems popup about the same time. And I sure don't understand why it is not taught to them how to use a debugger, because almost all of them would be easily solved by just running the code through a debugger, which is certainly faster than waiting for some answer and more educating.

Comment: @Flydog57 Some may argue [there's already an in-group bias](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/198/should-there-be-anonymous-answers-and-questions) and this suggestion would only stimulate that. Not everybody with rep 1 is a noob or a [leech](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/262365/can-i-avoid-being-a-leech-when-i-am-a-beginner-in-a-topic-and-only-ask-questio).

Comment: But, then again, @JonSkeet masqueraded as Daisy Shipton for 6 months (https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2018/09/19/farewell-daisy-shipton/) and picked up 12k rep.  I'm never going to get 12k rep in 6 months.  Not everyone with a 1 rep is a noob or a leech (we all started that way), but, in general, folks with >1000 rep do ask better questions (or, they should)

Answer (score 12):

There are more and more users here, most of whom ask terrible "questions", with the end result that good questions are buried in the noise. Similarly, even if experienced users are able to find those good questions, there's proportionally fewer of those experienced users available to answer them. Finally, many experienced users have left Stack Overflow for numerous reasons, the declining levels of quality and thus decreasing possibility to find quality being only one of those reasons.

To put it in simpler terms: the signal has stayed around the same, but noise has increased exponentially to the point where you have to spend almost all your time searching for that signal as opposed to listening to it - and a lot of people just aren't interested in doing that.

Answer (score 9):

There’s definitely a problem with the first query (version 1).

Some questions from 2010 were answered in 30 seconds, some a year, and some took a decade. Let’s say the average time to get an answer is 20 days. Some questions aren’t answered but they’re not included in this average.

Questions were asked in the week before the last SEDE update. Let’s look at the worst case scenario: not many were answered and the average time to get an answer was about 7 days (nobody got an answer until right before the refresh!). Maybe all the remaining questions are so hard that they’ll take 30 years to get an answer: the graph can’t tell us that. The average cannot be more than 7 because that inner join only looks at answered questions.

Instead you should probably look at something else, like what percent of questions get an answer within 7 days. (Due to Roomba it’s possible that deleted questions may skew the numbers.)

Comment: That's a good suggestion. I will try to change the query and come back. Thanks.

Comment: I have changed the question based on your suggestion and now the graph seems to indicate a trend. Not sure if the query is correct or fails to consider some aspects though.

Comment: This phenomenon is known as [censoring](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Censoring_(statistics)).

Answer (score 7):

> I am not asking a lot of questions on Stack Overflow, but for about 2-3 years I feel that I need to wait for more (and more frequently place a bounty) to get an answer.

These are related. You've gotten better at not only formulating your questions, but also at generating answers yourself. This means that you're able to do more research independently and answer your own questions when one is readily available or not too difficult to determine. In other words, you don't *have* fewer questions; you just need to pose fewer of them to other people. Because you're doing the research yourself now, the questions you do actually need help with are necessarily going to be more obscure and more difficult to research. The result is that your questions are more difficult to answer and require more expertise, so there are fewer people with the time or knowledge to be able to provide an answer or even guidance on where to look next.